# How to train multiple neural network models with Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, ensemble-learning

I'm interested in training an ensemble of models that are both diverse and accurate. I wanted to experiment with different hyper-parameter settings, architectures, initializations and optimizers. I was wondering if there's a TensorFlow equivalent of `graph scope` or `session scope` in Keras? Is there an equivalent of `tf.global_variables_initializer()` in Keras? What are some good ways of training multiple models in Keras?